# Split Comma Separated Values Into Array And Find Matches to Pre-set Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I have raw data that looks like the following:
[image]

The values are separated by commas, in this string I am looking for numbers in the range (1,2,3,4,5). If all five found it should return a 100% match.

In case only 4 numbers of this range are found then it should return 80%, for 3 numbers 60%, for 2 numbers 40%, for 1 number 20% and in case none are found it should return "none".
[image]

My thought was to split my comma separated values into an array. I got stuck at the first match (i.e. finding 100%).

```vb
Sub CheckNumberMatches()

Dim i As Long
Dim Elem As Variant
Dim myArr As Variant

With Worksheets("data")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        myArr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",")

        ' loop through array elements and look for 1,2,3,4,5
        For Each Elem In myArr
            If Elem Like "1,2,3,4,5" Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = "100%"
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Elem

    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

A few more examples:

- The main criteria is (1,2,3,4,5) needs to be found in the cell, but this does not need to be in numerical order, i.e. can be random (2,4,1,3,5). If all these numbers are found in **any order** it should be 100%.
- If all five numbers are found (1,2,3,4,5), but the cell includes other numbers (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) - it should be counted as 100%.
- The data can have gaps, i.e. it can be a range of (5,2,7,11,12). This should be counted as 40% (2 out of 5 numbers are found).
- Duplicate numbers are not possible.

Comment: I think you first need to define more precisely your requirements: Is `2,3,4,5` (without 1) 80% or 0%? Is the order always fix or can you have input strings like `2,3,5,1,4` (and if yes, is that 100%?). Can you have duplicates (`1,2,3,1,3,2,6`)? Are gaps possible (`1,3,4,7`)?

Comment: Hi @FunThomas - thanks for replying to my question. Apologies for not clarifying that in the main post. 2,3,4,5 would be 80%. It can be in a random order like your example (2,3,5,1,4) - in that case it would still be counted as 100%. Duplicates are not possible, but gaps are possible, and in case of gaps it should count how many of them it has. Let me edit my main post as well to provide more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Array approach**

Instead of looping through each cell in column "A" which can be time consuming, you can benefit from using arrays:

- Assign data to 1-based 2-dim data field array (see section 3),
- analyze each splitted element `cur` in a single loop (section 4), where *counting* the result of `Match()` with two array inputs receives the wanted information in one go via

  `Application.Count(Application.Match(cur, base, 0))`

  *Note that `Application.Count()` neglects errors resulting from non-findings.*
- All infos are reassigned to the data array and written back via `rng.Offset(, 1) = data`

```
Sub FoundBaseNumbers()
With Tabelle1
'1. Assign needed base numbers to 1-dim array
    Dim base As Variant: base = Split("1,2,3,4,5", ",")
'2. Define data range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
'3. Assign data to 1-based 2-dim data field array
    Dim data As Variant: data = rng.Value2
'4. Analyze data
    Dim i As Long, cur As Variant, cnt As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(data)
    'a) count findings of current elements
        cur = Split(data(i, 1), ",")
        cnt = Application.Count(Application.Match(cur, base, 0))
    'b) remember percentages using data field array
        data(i, 1) = IIf(cnt, Format(cnt / (UBound(base) + 1), "0%"), "None")
    Next i
'5. Write data to neighbour column
    rng.Offset(, 1) = data
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You started off well for your code. There are many ways something like this can be done. I've done up a simple way for you utiziling your code already. Have a look below and see if it's right for you.

I used `Select Case` as it allows to check for multiple things a lot easier than an `If` statement. You can even use ranges like `Case 1 To 10`. You can also do multiple `Case` lines to have different results do different things (like an `ElseIf`) etc.

```
Sub CheckNumberMatches()

Dim i As Long, Elem As Variant, myArr As Variant, Counter As Long

With Worksheets("data")
    For i = 1 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        myArr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, ",")
        Counter = 0
        ' loop through array elements and look for 1,2,3,4,5
        For Each Elem In myArr
            Select Case Elem
                Case 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
                    Counter = Counter + 1
            End Select
        Next
        If Counter > 0 Then
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = Format(Counter / 5, "0%")
        Else
            .Cells(i, "B").Value = "None"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I wrote something very similar but used an if statement `If (UBound(Filter(myArr, i)) > -1) Then` because i thought it was simpler than the select :)